# How to Debug ping / telnet takes time to resolve the host

Tags: linux, networking, dns, ping

If I ping a dns record like `ping google.com` it'll take 4 seconds before getting the first request then it's instant, same for telnet.

but if I `ping 142.250.201.174` it's instant.

I don't know how to debug the issue, the latency is really painful, it's a server and everything times out.

```
root@kubeapp-04:~# ping google.com

... Taking it's time ...


PING google.com (142.250.178.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from par21s22-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=120 time=2.09 ms
64 bytes from par21s22-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.142): icmp_seq=2 ttl=120 time=2.44 ms
64 bytes from par21s22-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.142): icmp_seq=3 ttl=120 time=2.22 ms
64 bytes from par21s22-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.178.142): icmp_seq=4 ttl=120 time=2.24 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.089/2.245/2.437/0.124 ms
root@kubeapp-04:~# ping google.com^C
root@kubeapp-04:~# nslookup google.com
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.250.201.174
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4007:81a::200e

root@kubeapp-04:~# telnet 142.250.201.174 80
Trying 142.250.201.174...
Connected to 142.250.201.174.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]

telnet> Connection closed.
root@kubeapp-04:~# telnet google.com 80

... Taking it's time ...


Trying 216.58.215.46...
Connected to google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]  

telnet> ^CConnection closed.
root@kubeapp-04:~# ping 216.58.215.46
PING 216.58.215.46 (216.58.215.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 216.58.215.46: icmp_seq=1 ttl=120 time=2.23 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.46: icmp_seq=2 ttl=120 time=2.45 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.46: icmp_seq=3 ttl=120 time=2.34 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.46: icmp_seq=4 ttl=120 time=2.34 ms

--- 216.58.215.46 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.233/2.340/2.449/0.076 ms
```

Comment: I suggest you download e.g. `mtr` (my traceroute) and do the same as above; you will see which routing step (hop) is causing a(any) delay(s). Or is it the DNS reply being slow?  Try setting 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4. as DNS temporarily.

Comment: @Hannu From the output of `nslookup` in the post, `8.8.8.8` is already being used as the nameserver.